In blazor, using @bind-checked on a loop of property info via reflection of a custom class
I have a class, MyModel, with over 100 properties (I know) that are all of bool? data type. I'm trying to dynamically generate two radio buttons (Yes / No) for each property instead of manually creating the controls for each. I'm able to achieve some of my desired output, but not bind the data with validation. The edit-form uses either a model or an edit context, I've tried both. (using syncfusion DataForm component)
First I tried just looping of the reflected property info.
@foreach (var prop in properties)
{
<label>@prop.name</label>
<radio button value=true @bind-checked=@prop.SetValue(MyModel)>
<radio button value=false @bind-checked=@prop.SetValue(MyModel)>
}

Next I tried using a dictionary to store the field name and bool value, but dictionaries are read-only in this context and cannot be two-way binded.
var dict = new Dictionary<PropertyInfo, bool?>;
(reflection here to set dictionary, setting bool? to null) 

@foreach (var kvp in dict)
{
<label>@kvp.Key.Name</label>
<radio button value=true @bind-checked=@kvp.value>
<radio button value=false @bind-checked=@kvp.value>
}


Then I changed the dictionary to include a 'wrapper' object so the value can be changed. This works except then I cant use the edit context/ model for validation.
var dict = new Dictionary<PropertyInfo, BoolWrapper?>;
@foreach (var kvp in dict)
{
<label>@kvp.Key.Name</label>
<radio button value=true @bind-checked=@kvp.value.YesNo>
<radio button value=false @bind-checked=@kvp.value.YesNo>
}

public class BoolWrapper
{
public bool? YesNo {get; set;}
}

I'm open to any ideas on how to make this possible. I considered making the model class indexable, but I'm still pretty new to C# and it adds a lot of complexity that I can't quite understand.
Any ideas on how to make this possible is greatly appreciated.

Following sample may helps:
@page "/"
@using System.Reflection
@rendermode InteractiveServer

<SfDataForm Model="PropertyVars" OnSubmit="HandleSubmit">
    <FormValidator>
        <DataAnnotationsValidator></DataAnnotationsValidator>
    </FormValidator>
    <FormItems>
        @foreach (var property in typeof(MyModel).GetProperties())
        {
            var propertyName = property.Name;
            <div>
                @propertyName
                <SfRadioButton Label="Yes" Name="@propertyName" Value="true" @bind-Checked="PropertyVars[propertyName]"></SfRadioButton>
                <SfRadioButton Label="No" Name="@propertyName" Value="false" @bind-Checked="PropertyVars[propertyName]"></SfRadioButton>
            </div>
        }
    </FormItems>
</SfDataForm>

@code{
    [SupplyParameterFromForm]
    public Dictionary<string, bool> PropertyVars { get; set; }

    private MyModel myModel = new();
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        if (PropertyVars == null)
        {
            PropertyVars = new();
            foreach (var property in typeof(MyModel).GetProperties())
            {
                PropertyVars.Add(property.Name, false);
            }
        }
    }

    private void HandleSubmit()
    {
        foreach (var property in typeof(MyModel).GetProperties())
        {
            property.SetValue(myModel, PropertyVars[property.Name]);
        }
        var result = myModel;
    }

    public class MyModel
    {
        public bool bool1 { get; set; }    
        public bool bool2 { get; set; }
        public bool bool3 { get; set; }
    }
}

Test result


